# How to use AlertDialog in xamarin Android when class has reference of Android.App and Android.Support.V7.App?

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I am trying to show alert dialog but it showing compile time error cos i have reference of following namespaces and My Alert dialog code sample:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Support.V7.App;

 public void btnDisplayClick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
       AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ct);
        alertDialog.SetTitle("Simple Alert Dialog");
        alertDialog.SetMessage("This is my simple Alert Dialog");
        alertDialog.SetNeutralButton("Ok", delegate
        {
            alertDialog.Dispose();
        });
        alertDialog.Show();
   }
```

It is showing compile time error as follows:
AlertDialog' is an ambiguous reference between 'Android.App.AlertDialog' and 'Android.Support.V7.App.AlertDialog

I tried using Namespace.ClassName but still showing error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 classes of AlertDialog available in Android source. One is in Android.App namespace and the other one is in Android.Support.V7.App.

You can just call the AlertDialog in code using [namespace].[class].
For example:

```
Android.Support.V7.App.AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new Android.Support.V7.App.AlertDialog.Builder(ct);
```

Comment: I tried that, still showing error, that's why i posted this question.

Comment: try use global::Android.Support.V7.App